# Use different SSH keys for different accounts on the same Git hosting

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

This question would be simple if I ask it as a use case. I have two SSH keys on my computer

1. personal_id_rsa
2. company_id_rsa

And I have two different user accounts on [bitbucket.org](http://bitbucket.org/). One of them is my personal account and the other is my company account. I have **N** number of repositories on my PC as well. Some of them has to be linked with my personal account and *some other* repos with the company account. There is no repositories that has to be linked to both the accounts. I have set the **Identityfile** inside the `~/.ssh/config` to something like below.

```
Host *.bitbucket.org
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company_id_rsa
```

And whenever I want to push something to my personal repos, I change the config file to something like below.

```
Host *.bitbucket.org
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal_id_rsa
```

And now, it becomes quite an inconvenience to edit the file whenever I want to make a `git push`. I was just thinking if I could just pickup one of the keys on the fly, when I *push*, it would have been a lot easier. Is there any way to do so?

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-without-using-ssh-config) question which explains a similar use case, but that is not the **exact** use case here.

Comment: as u referred that qsn,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add two Bitbucket "accounts" in your ssh config file. Bitbucket has alternative ssh host listening on port 443 (For those who has blocked almost all ports (sic!)).

```
Host bitbucketCompany
    User git
    HostName altssh.bitbucket.org
    Port 443
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company_id_rsa

Host bitbucketWork
    User git
    HostName bitbucket.org
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal_id_rsa
```

Then update your remotes in .git/config

Company projects

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://bitbucketCompany/username/repo.git
```

Personal projects

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://bitbucketPersonal/username/repo.git
```

Comment: Ok, this answer has given me a pointer to this resource. https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168. Accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways.

- Git consults the environment variable `GIT_SSH` to know which SSH client to use.  If it's not set, it reverts to its built-in default (it's just `ssh` or `ssh.exe`, depending on the platform, IIRC), so you can do this:

  ```
  $ cat >~/bin/bb-priv-ssh
  #!/bin/sh
  /usr/bin/ssh -i /path/to/my/private/ssh/key
  ^D
  $ chmod +x $_
  $ cat >~/bin/bb-corp-ssh
  #!/bin/sh
  /usr/bin/ssh -i /path/to/my/corporate/ssh/key
  ^D
  $ chmod +x $_
  ```

  Now you'll be able to do this

  ```
  $ GIT_SSH=~/bin/bb-priv-ssh git push
  $ GIT_SSH=~/bin/bb-corp-ssh git push
  ```

  or just

  ```
  $ export GIT_SSH=~/bin/bb-priv-ssh
  ```

  before opening a session in which you do your private work; "corporate settion" would be set up like this with the obvious adjustment.

  Note that you can't just use `GIT_SSH='/usr/bin/ssh -i /path/to/a/key/file'` as Git expects this variable to contain just a pathname.  I'm lazy to google at the moment for relevant [`comp.lang.version-control.git`](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git.user) articles on this — please do this yourself if needed.
- Start using the [SSH key agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent).  You can then add to it both keys, and it will attempt to use both of them when authenticating — one will fail, and the other one succeed.  This makes the login process longer for an unfortunate host (one more round of authentication round-trips) but in this case, I reckon, it's a reasonable price to pay for convenience.

Comment: Infact, the first method requires a bit of `unlearning`, where I flawlessly start typing a git command. And the second needs another software. I found this and it appears to be solving the issue for me : https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168. I will update you after giving it a test. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION**

I'm keeping the other answer as accepted, because that pointed me to the [correct solution, here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168). I removed all the existing keys from my machine and created two completely new ones, namely `personalid` and `companyid`.

```
$ ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/personalid -C "My Personal SSH Key"
$ ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/companyid -C "My Company SSH Key"
```

And after that, added both to appropriate accounts on bitbucket. Then I created the following SSH `config` file and everything works like a charm. Since *I don't have any repositories that has to be pushed to both the company and the personal accounts*, this solution requires no additional hacks to make it working.

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personalid

Host company
  HostName bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/companyid

Host personal
  HostName bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personalid
```

And when pushing, do it normally as you do, `git push <your stuff>` and it will pick the appropriate key which is uploaded on bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the host is the same, your git config file should look something like this:

```
# Set up SSH keys for personal and work projects
Host gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    User git
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    IdentitiesOnly yes

    # Personal projects
    Match User personalmail@gmail.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
    # Work projects
    Match User workmail@workmail.ai
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Just change your email and host. Also, I have 2 ssh key pairs created with 2 different algorithms, but you don't have to.