# SourceTree how to load my account username & email (from bitbucket, github)?

Tags: github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

Hello I am on multiple git websites like bitbucket, github & co. I have different usernames & emails but Sourcetree forces me to type my name and email. So it doesn't load itself.

It is not possible to use my account information from their website without to login ( on the website) and look for my email and typ in sourcetree? Its little bit annoying to this on new projects.

EDIT: What I mean is in other words: I want to have load my account information  automated from bitbucket, github so **I do not need type everytime on new repo** and check everytime on their website what username or email was set up.

Just as question if it is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Work With Two Different BitBucket Accounts In SourceTree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048618/how-to-work-with-two-different-bitbucket-accounts-in-sourcetree)

Comment: Thanks I saw this already but this isn't my problem. I can setup multiple information for different git server. That's no problem but I wanted to have automated.. not typing my information which I need to get from their website everytime ::S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just as question if it is possible

Not really.
What I do is:

- make sure I don't have any global user.name/user.email (see "[How do I make git block commits if user email isn't set?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292895/6309)")

  ```
  git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
  ```
- use an alias to set the authorship data I want

On Windows, I define those aliases as:

```
doskey gcu=git config user.name "Name1" ^&^& git config user.email email1@com
doskey gcu2=git config user.name "Name2" ^&^& git config user.email email2@com
```

Then, in a repo, I typo (only once) `gcu` or `gcu2`, depending on the nature of that repo.

If I forget to type it, I won't be able to create a commit without the error message:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: no name was given and auto-detection is disabled
```